# is there a way to change the function name of the click event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to change the method name inside v-on:click="function1",
but when I hardcode function1 inside the html, button works and function1 executes but when I pass the "function1" attribute thruogh the Vue's data property, the button does not work and the function1 does not execute. please help me. thanks

```
button type="button" v-on:click="obj.continueButton" class="btn">Continue</button>

var test = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
    obj : { 
            continueButton: 'function1'
    }
```

Comment: You are probably doing it wrong. What you need to achieve with this code?

Comment: I want to be able to change the function of the button somewhere with this code   this.obj.continueButton = 'secondFunc';

Comment: Is there any error showing up in the console after clicking the button ?

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: handler.apply is not a function"

(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue.js:634
logError @ vue.js:1893
globalHandleError @ vue.js:1888
handleError @ vue.js:1848
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.js:1871
invoker @ vue.js:2184
original._wrapper @ vue.js:7547
vue.js:1897 TypeError: handler.apply is not a function
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.js:1863)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.js:2184)
    at HTMLButtonElement.original._wrapper (vue.js:7547)

Comment: This is occurring due to `obj.continueButton` having a string value instead of a function.

Comment: Also, where exactly have you defined `function1` ?

Comment: it is solved by Hannah's asnwer. thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited an earlier answer which was incorrect)

You could try it this way instead:

```
<button type="button" v-on:click="execFn(obj.continueButton)" class="btn">
  Continue
</button>

...
data: {
  obj: {
    continueButton: 'function1'
  }
},
methods: {
  execFn(name) {
    this[name]();
  },
  function1() {
    // do something
  },
  function2() {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: it is unclear, i didn't get it, what about the function2 ?

Comment: I have expanded my example to show that you can define as many functions as you want, even if you change the value of `obj.continueButton` it should execute correctly.

Comment: No problem, sorry I wasn't clear enough at first :)